# Change the button type for validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I am using formvalidation.io library to validate a Bootstrap form. The default behavior for this library is activation by the time a submit button was clicked.

Now I want to have more than one button and activate them based on a session variable from the server side script. But how can I use the validation with "non-submit" buttons? Here is a sample code which uses the formvalidation default validation process:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myForm').formValidation({
        framework: 'bootstrap',
        icon: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            'name': {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Please provide your name.'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: I wanna use some buttons like this:
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Button</button>

Comment: Documentation? http://formvalidation.io/examples/using-multiple-buttons/

Comment: This does not work. I want to show some buttons as disabled while using this solution, all buttons become activated by the time of form validation.

Comment: Also ask here: https://twitter.com/formvalidation/